# Join without removing unique lines in Linux

Tags: text-processing, join

I have a table A:

```
1 n m n ...
2 m n m ...
3 n m n ...
4 m n m ...
5 n m n ...
```

I have a table B:

```
1 A
3 B
5 C
```

I want to join the column 2 of table B with table A by matching column 1 of both tables, without removing the unique lines in table A to get the following (for no matches write a "NA"):

```
1 A  n m n ...
2 NA m n m ...
3 B  n m n ...
4 NA m n m ...
5 C  n m n ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `man join`

```
   -a FILENUM
          also  print unpairable lines from file FILENUM, where FILENUM is
          1 or 2, corresponding to FILE1 or FILE2

   -e EMPTY
          replace missing input fields with EMPTY
```

so

```
join -a1 -e 'NA' -o 0,2.2,1.2,1.3,1.4 A B
1 A n m n
2 NA m n m
3 B n m n
4 NA m n m
5 C n m n
```